# Unrar all .rar files in a directory to a folder with the same name

Tags: linux, command-line, compression, rar

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

I have a folder (called 'dir') that contains the following:

```
dir
|_sub1.rar
|_sub2.rar
|_sub3.rar
```

I will cd ~/ to dir and want to run a command that will extract all .rar files and place the contents into a folder with the same name. sub1.rar should be extracted to sub1, sub2.rar should be extracted to sub2, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set -e
cd dir
for rar in ./*.rar
do
  [ -f "$rar" ] || continue
  dir=${rar%.rar}
  mkdir "$dir"
  (
     cd "./$dir"
     unrar x "../$rar"
  )
  # maybe rm "$rar"
done
```

Nothing clever here. Assumes you have an `unrar` command that takes an `x` option to do the eXtract. Just run a loop over the things matching ./*.rar, make sure it is a file, make a directory, then use a subshell to change directory and extract it.

Comment: I ran a test with this and it seemed to be working fine but only extracted the first file then it closed the terminal down. I used an example for the directory being 'dir' but in reality it changes. Do I need to change the $dir to the actual path? I tried that but didnt work.

Comment: im also not sure if by calling the compressed  "files" maybe was the wrong terminology, There is a parent folder (which changes) and then a long list of subdirectories that are all compressed with rar. It would be nice to take out the cd in the command as I will cd into the parent folder first then run a command from there.

Comment: For things you want to do more than once,  the best idea is to put this into a file (a "shell script"). For flexibility I agree that the "cd dir" shouldn't be in the script, but I was just trying to match what I understood to be your requirements. There are 2 things with "dir" in them. At the start there is the hard coded one, to match your requirement. Then there is a variable which is the part of the rar file without the ".rar" on the end. Does this make sense?